# How do I take full ownership of all files on a BlackArmor 440 NAS?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, nas

I have a Seagate BlackArmor 440 NAS. I am accessing it as the administrator on a Windows 7 machine. When I try to change permissions on a folder on the NAS I am denied with the following message:

An error occurred while applying security information to:

X:[myfoldername]

Access is denied.

The current owner is Unix User/root but I am not logged in with a Unix system. When I try to add a user or group from the Advanced tab in security settings the only location listed under Locations is the NAS itself, so I can't add a user from the Windows machine.